# post a comment vs. low reputation

Tags: discussion, comments

Why do we need *some* reputation to post a comment?

It's very hard to ask for any additional information of someone who posted an answer; and if you put your question in another answer, other users will downvote that "answer".

Comment: While I'm here, might I make a suggestion? Looking through your questions, all of them appear to have grammar and capitalization issues. It would likely help you greatly in the long run if you work on improving that in your questions. Good English grammar skills are valued here. :)

Comment: I've suggested an edit on one of your questions to help out. Feel free to reject it, or if it gets approved, roll it back, but editing for proper grammar could help you get your questions upvoted, which could get you the rep you need to comment.

Comment: Additionally, most of your answers are just links or code dumps. If you add explanation to answers, you will be much more likely to get upvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, anyone can comment on their own posts, regardless of reputation, so the issue of getting additional information is moot in these common use cases (so if you asked a question, you can comment on that question and all answers on the question, and for an answer, you can comment on it).

The restriction is there to help guard against spam and to teach people that comments should not be used for extended discussion.

50 reputation is not difficult to get - a few accepted suggested edits (if you don't feel you can ask/answer well enough).